# How to replace non-ASCII characters in a sequence?

Tags: java, string, unicode, ascii

Essentially, what this code does is:

- Take an input.
- Replace each sequence of characters whose length is greater than 2 with the number of times that character repeated and the character itself (e.g. `jjjkkkkkllll` = `3j5k4l`). The input does not contain any numeric values.
- Return the result.

The code:

```
private String replaceConsecutiveChars(String data) {
    char[] dataChars = data.toCharArray();

    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    Character charType = null;
    for(Character c : dataChars) {
        if(k == dataChars.length - 1 && i >= 2) {
            data = data.replace(repeat(String.valueOf(charType), ++i), (i + Character.toString(charType)));
            break;
        }

        if(i == 0) {
            charType = c;
            i++;
        }else if(c == charType) {
            i++;
        }else if(c != charType && i > 2) {
            data = data.replace(repeat(String.valueOf(charType), i), (i + Character.toString(charType)));

            i = 1;
            charType = c;
        }else if(c != charType && i <= 2) {
            i = 1;
            charType = c;
        }

        k++;
    }

    return data;
}

private String repeat(String s, int n) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> s).limit(n).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

However, my implementation only seems to work with the limited-ASCII character set, but I am trying to get it work with the Unicode character set. For example:

- The input `ddddddddkkkkkpppp` will correctly output `8d5k4p`.
- The input `êêêêÌÌÌÌÌÌÌØØØ` will incorrectly output `êêêêÌÌÌÌÌÌÌØØØ`
- The input `"rrrrrêêêêÌÌÌÌÌkkkkØØØ"` will incorrectly output `5rêêêêÌÌÌÌÌ4kØØØ`

Why is this?

In addition, is there a better way I could do this than the way I'm doing it right now?

Comment: Why use the Character wrapper class?

Comment: So I can use `null`.

Comment: The only place you use that is for the character you are saving over the loops. Seems rather silly. Why don't you use a char and assign it the value of '1' initially as you know you will never loop over a number in your loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing instances of Character using `==`, which will not work as expected because the operator compares object references instead of values.

A simple quick fix is to change the for-loop to:

```
for (char c : dataChars) {
}
```

Notice the change of types (Character to char). This way `charType` is automatically unboxed to the primitive *char* when comparing it to `c`.

Another solution is to replace every `c == charType` with `c.equals(charType)` to not compare references, but values.